# Divide all columns by particular column, except one

Tags: r

For example : I have frame with 4 columns and I want divide columns A and B by C, but I want unchanged column ID

```
A   B   C   ID

4   8   23  1
5   12  325 2
6   23  56  3
73  234 21  4
23  23  213 5
```

The result which i expect is

```
     A           B      C   ID
0,173913043 0,347826087 1   1
0,015384615 0,036923077 1   2
0,107142857 0,410714286 1   3
3,476190476 11,14285714 1   4
0,107981221 0,107981221 1   5
```

or without the column C, doesn't matter

So, I have the code which give me only columns A and B without the column 'ID'

```
columns_to_divide <- c(1,2)
results <- results[,columns_to_divide ]/results[,3]
```

Comment: You need to assign just to the divided columns `results[, columns_to_divide] <-`, not overwriting the whole data frame `results <-`. Just like if you want to change the first column to `0` you could use `results[, 1] <- 0` not `results <- 0`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate`, which creates or alters the values in a column. `across` says to alter columns A and B, and then we can define a function to divide both of these columns by C.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate(across(c(A, B), function(x) x/C))
```

```
            A           B   C ID
1: 0.17391304  0.34782609  23  1
2: 0.01538462  0.03692308 325  2
3: 0.10714286  0.41071429  56  3
4: 3.47619048 11.14285714  21  4
5: 0.10798122  0.10798122 213  5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div = c("A", "B")
div_by = "C"
DF[div] <- DF[div] / DF[[div_by]]

#            A           B   C
# 1 0.17391304  0.34782609  23
# 2 0.01538462  0.03692308 325
# 3 0.10714286  0.41071429  56
# 4 3.47619048 11.14285714  21 
# 5 0.10798122  0.10798122 213
```

Data

```
DF data.frame(
  A = c(4, 5, 6, 73, 23), B = c(8, 12, 23, 234, 23), C = c(23, 325, 56, 21, 213)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Columns

```
A <- c(4, 5, 6, 73, 23)
B <- c(8, 12, 23, 234, 23)
C <- c(23, 325, 56, 21, 213)
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Add to data frame

```
df = data.frame(A, B, C, ID)
```

divide by and print

```
df$A <- df$A / df$C
df$B <- df$B / df$C
df$C <- df$C / df$C

print(df)
```